# A particular entry in a worksheet cannot be assigned to a public variable

Tags: excel, vba, scope

When the loop reaches Row 23 in the worksheet shown below, it encounters the Item cell highlighted in yellow. The `i.Value` correctly shows 43P500KJP.
When `myItem = i.Value` is executed the variable `myItem` is Nothing.

I changed the scope of the variable `myItem` but that made no difference.
Other longer items names work OK as in the other cells in Bold in my sample Worksheet do.
I made sure that the format of cell C23 is the same as the other cells in Bold in Column C.
I tried `myItem = i.Text`,  `myAnswer = i.Value` where the scopes are `Public myAnswer`, `Dim myItem As Variant`, `Dim myItem as String`.

[image: OpenSOs2.jpg]

```vb
Sub FindBold()
' Finds Item name and address for "Bold" Items in column C by finding cells which are in Bold font
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OpenSOs").Select
    Dim myRange As Rang
    Dim i As Range
    For Each i In [C3:C375]
    If i.Font.FontStyle = "Bold" Then
        myItem = i.Value
        myStartSORow = i.Row
        If myStartSORow = 375 Then
            myStop = True
        End If
    End If 
    Next i
End Sub
```

I changed the string in the cell that shows up the error.

The following do not show an error:

```
43P500APJ, 43P500AAA, 43P500PJK, 43P500123
```

The following show an error:

```
43P500AJK, 43P500AJP, 43P500KPJ
```

I used `Dim myItem As String` ahead of all procedures.

Comment: If you put `Debug.Print i.Row, i.Font.Fontstyle` after `For Each i In [C3:C375]`, what is the output in the Immediate Window?

Comment: Thank you BigBen, The immediate window correctly reports the Bold font in the correct rows which includes Row 23. as well as rows, 3, 17, 23, 27 and 37. Thank you for your prompt interest.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with `myItem`? What other code do you have? Where exactly is `myItem` nothing?

Comment: HI BigBen. myItem is used in another Find to search for rows of data in another worksheet. The mystery is that myItem in my code, is immediately under the line 
If i.Font.FontStyle = "Bold" Then    If I hover my mouse over i.Value the true value is shown but when I execute the line myItem does not pick up the Value at all as though there were Nothing there. This anomaly doesn't happen with any other values of "i" The variable myStartSORow in the row below the myItem row DOES pick up the i.Row value.

Comment: It would probably be best to avoid using `Public` variables like this, if that's what you're doing. I can't really help further w/o you sharing more code unfortunately.

Comment: FURTHER IMPORTANT DATA: I've tried changing the string in the cell that shows up the error.

Comment: FURTHER IMPORTANT DATA: I've tried changing the string in the cell that shows up the error. 
The following DO NOT show an error: 43P500APJ, 43P500AAA, 43P500PJK, 43P500123
The following DO SHOW an error: 43P500AJK, 43P500AJP, 43P500KPJ.
Just how weird is this? Any thoughts guys?? I've used Dim myItem As String ahead of all Procedures.